# Calculate the latitude / longitude coordinates of the location where the Sun is at the zenith

Tags: astronomy, sun, coordinate-systems

There are plenty of resources showing how to calculate zenith and azimuth of the Sun when the time and the location are given.

However, I need to calculate the location where the sun is at the zenith for a given time and date, not the other way around. Is there a more or less easy way to do this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I found a solution - it's actually pretty simple:

- Latitude is the declination of the sun
- Longitude is the right ascension minus GMST (Greenwich Mean Sidereal Time)

Sample Code for Java: (The equations are from [here](http://lexikon.astronomie.info/zeitgleichung/neu.html) (german))

```
private static double dateToJulianDate(Date date) {
    return date.getTime() / dayMs - 0.5 + J1970;
}



public static HashMap<String, Double> sunPos(Date date)
{
    double J = dateToJulianDate(date);
    double T = (J - J2000)/36525d;
    double M = 2*Math.PI * (0.993133 + 99.997361 * T );
    double L = 2*Math.PI * (0.7859453 + M/(2*Math.PI) + (6893.0*Math.sin(M)+72.0*Math.sin(2.0*M)+6191.2*T) / 1296000d);
    double e = 2*Math.PI * (23.43929111 + (-46.8150*T - 0.00059*T*T + 0.001813*T*T*T)/3600.0d)/360d;
    double DK = Math.asin(Math.sin(e)*Math.sin(L));
    double RA = Math.atan(Math.tan(L)*Math.cos(e));
    double GMST = Math.abs(getSiderealTime(J,0)%(2*Math.PI));


    if(RA < 0) RA      = RA + Math.PI;
    if(L > Math.PI) RA = RA + Math.PI;


    double lat = DK*57.2957795;
    double lon = (RA - GMST)*57.2957795;

    HashMap<String, Double> ret = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    ret.put("lat",lat);
    ret.put("lon",lon);

    return ret;

}
```